# When using BeautifulSoup to search for html tags, why does it find a 'pagecontainer' but not anything inside it?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a glimpse of the page container which has the information I'd like to scrape:

```
<page-container><div class="frame-layout frame-layout--pp">
    <div class="collapsed-header ng-hide" ng-show="$ctrl.showCollapsedHeader" ng-class="{'collapsed-header--show': $ctrl.showCollapsedHeader}">
        <div class="frame-layout">
            <div class="left-hand-side">
                <a class="collapsed-header__logo" ng-href="/bet" href="/bet">
                  <svg class="collapsed-header__img">
                      <use xlink:href="sprite_72607c11c0715ccc829d7aef33133030.svg#logos-header_logo-usage"></use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="center"></div>
            <div class="right-hand-side"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <aside class="left-hand-side" style="min-height: 1584px;">
        <div class="left-hand-side__container" responsive-side-menu="" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;">
            <navigation main="$ctrl.navigationMainPageViewModel" az-list="$ctrl.navigationAzPageViewModel" on-price-format-toggle="$ctrl.onPriceFormatToggle(priceFormat)" on-open-menu-link="$ctrl.onOpenNavigationMenuLink(event, item)" on-nav-item-click="$ctrl.onNavItemClick(event, item)" current-location-path="$ctrl.currentLocationPath"><div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__page" ng-class="{'menu__page--animate-left': $ctrl.azBettingSectionVisible}">
                # etc, about 1000 lines with the usual sects, items, div, abc etc.
                # section class="mod-games-widget pp vertical games-widget no-tabs"
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
</page-container>
```

This is the only page container in the webpage.
However, when I try

```
print(soup.find("page-container"))
```

I get just

```
<page-container></page-container>
```

and BeautifulSoup fails to return any of the tags inside the page container like the 'aside' and 'div' tags (it finds the div tags which are outside the page container).

Does anyone know why it could be that nothing inside the page container gets found?

EDIT:
Minimum reproducible example:

```
resp = requests.get("https://www.paddypower.com/football/uefa-champions-league?tab=outrights")
if resp.status_code == 200:
  print("Y")
  print(soup.find("page-container"))
  for tag in soup.findAll("aside"):
    print(tag) # Prints empty list
  for tag in soup.findAll("div"):
    print(tag) # Prints div tags, but none of the ones in the page container
else:
  print("N")
```

Comment: I think that beautifulsoup is not rendering the js that generates that html. I would suggest to use selenium to render and download the page and then feed the rendered html to beautifulsoup.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for a detailed answer

Comment: @Pitto , provided an MPE at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I don't have a PC to test, please double check for possible errors.

You need the [chromedriver for your platform too](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), put it in the same folder of the script.

My idea would be to use selenium to get the HTML and then parse it:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.paddypower.com/football/uefa-champions-league?tab=outrights"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.findAll("aside"):
    print(tag) # Prints empty list
for tag in soup.findAll("div"):
    print(tag) # Prints div tags, but none of the ones in the page container
else:
  print("N")
```